# Button.Click event doesn't fire after TextBox.Leave event

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I use the below code to verify if the text into a TextBox was changed and ask for saving changes:

```
Private TBoxTxtBefore As String = String.Empty

Private Sub TextBox1_Enter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Enter
    Try
        TBoxTxtBefore = CType(sender, TextBox).Text
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
    Try
        If CType(sender, TextBox).Text <> TBoxTxtBefore Then
            Dim SN As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Save changes?", vbYesNo, "Save Changes")
            If SN = vbYes Then Btn_SaveChanges.PerformClick()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

But when I click a button (for example `button1`) while the cursor is inside `TextBox1`, only `TextBox1.Leave` event was raised.

How can I have `Button?.click` event raise after `TextBox1.Leave` event?

Comment: Edit this question and show the button1 click event as well as Btn_SaveChanges click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I have button1.click event raise after TextBox1.Leave event?

If TextBox1 has the focus and you click a button the leave event will fire before the click event.  To test click in Texbox1, then click Button1.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Debug.WriteLine("B1C")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Debug.WriteLine("B2C")
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
    Debug.WriteLine("TBL")
    Button2.PerformClick()
End Sub
```

Try to clarify your question please.

edit:  This recreates the problem I think you are having,

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Debug.WriteLine("B1C")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Debug.WriteLine("B2C")
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
    MessageBox.Show("FOO")
    Debug.WriteLine("TBL")
    Button2.PerformClick()
End Sub
```

Did some searching and found that the Message box causes pending focus events to be lost.

Comment: button1.click event isn't fired

Comment: Edit your question and show the button1 click event as well as Btn_SaveChanges click event.

Comment: Button1.click is for example. Everywhere I click no event is raised after `TextBox1.Leave`

Comment: Did you try the example I posted?  Does it work?  You have to post at least one buttons code or we can't help.

Comment: Ok you found the issue (+1). I tried removing the msgboxes and the event was fired. Now is there any way to fire the event without removing the confirmation msgboxes?

Comment: I accepted your answer because you showed me the way to get the button clicked by referencing the focus and so the active control. ;)

Comment: @genespos - a solution would depend on how many other user events could be triggered with the user in the textbox.  How complicated is the form?

Comment: I solved using Me.Activecontrol at the top of leave event

Comment: @genespos - post your fix as an answer so that if others have the problem they will know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to dbasnett's hints I was able to get the name of the control that fired the Leave event, so to call it (if it's a button) after the Message Box was showed:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
    Try
        Dim FiringCtrl As Control = Me.Activecontrol
        If CType(sender, TextBox).Text <> TBoxTxtBefore _
           AndAlso FiringCtrl.Name <> "Btn_SaveChanges" Then
            Dim SN As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Save changes?", vbYesNo, "Save Changes")
            If SN = vbYes Then Btn_SaveChanges.PerformClick()
            If TypeOf FiringCtrl Is Button Then 
                DirectCast(FiringCtrl, Button).PerformClick()
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

**Anyway Plutonix showed me a better solution** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539211/catch-the-control-button-click-who-raised-the-leave-event-on-a-textbox)

Answer (score -1):

You can call multiple events one after the another. Your TextBox1_Leave event could trigger Button1_click event.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave

  'Take the control to another sub. Pass the sender control and the event details as arguments
  Call Button1_Click(sender,e)

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
'Do your stuff here

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But I don't know what event I need to raise. It doesn't matter where I click, the only event raised is `TextBox1.Leave` and not the other I've clicked.

Comment: This isn't **firing the event**. This is just calling another method. Also this just doesn't address the OP's question.